# Using envalid in React project throws runtime error [envalid] Env var not found: $$typeof

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables

I am getting an error when I use [envalid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envalid) in my React application. Version of envalid is 7.1.1:

> ReferenceError: [envalid] Env var not found: $$typeof

Usage of envalid in my app is like this:

```js
import { cleanEnv, str } from 'envalid';

const ENV = cleanEnv(process.env, {
  NODE_ENV: str({ default: 'development' }),
  REACT_APP_SOME_VALUE: str({ default: 'default value' }),
});

export default ENV;
```

When i use `ENV` in my application I get the error mentioned above:

```
console.log(ENV.REACT_APP_SOME_VALUE);
```

If I don't use it, i don't get the error. So it seems that it is throwing error when getting a value from `ENV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was a bit ad hoc but it works for now.

I just bumped version to `7.2.0-beta.2`.

This answer helped me with this: https://github.com/af/envalid/issues/150#issuecomment-884634438

It seems that it is a new problem since the beta fix was done yesterday.

I will update my answer if it gets fixed in regular version with new update.